# .js component in a .tsx component - no overload matches this call/property does not exist on type IntrinsicAttributes

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am trying to include a .jsx (or .js) React class stateful component in the render() function of a .tsx function component.
I get different errors 'No attribute matches this call' according to the things I try.

I tried things I saw on github, like:

```
//...
  /* tslint:disable */
  const JSProfileDetails: any = ProfileDetails; 
  /* tslint:enable */

  return (
// ...
   <JSProfileDetails
        profileName={profileName}
        profileDetails={profileDetails}
        profileInitialValues={profileInitialValues}
      />
```

but literally nothing works so far.
I keep that component in .jsx/.js because it's fairly impossible to type it.

I am on `typescript@3.7.2` and my `tsconfig.json` is:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "outDir": "build/dist",
    "module": "esnext",
    "target": "es6",
    "lib": ["es2019", "dom"],
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "jsx": "react",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "noImplicitThis": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "strictNullChecks": false,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true,
    "types": ["react", "node", "jest"],
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "skipLibCheck" : true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true
  },
  "exclude": [
    "node_modules",
    "build",
    "scripts",
    "acceptance-tests",
    "webpack",
    "jest",
    "src/setupTests.ts"
  ]
}
```

the exact error I'm getting is:

```
o overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 2, '(props: TypographyProps, context?: any): ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (props: any) => Componen
t<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<any, any, any>)> | Component<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ElementType<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>>'.
  Overload 2 of 2, '(props: PropsWithChildren<TypographyProps>, context?: any): ReactElement<any, string | ((props: any) => ReactElement<any, string | ... | (new (prop
s: any) => Component<any, any, any>)>) | (new (props: any) => Component<...>)> | Component<...>', gave the following error.
    Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ElementType<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>>'.
```

and at the same time, the VS code error is:

```
Type '{ profileName: string; modelId: string; definitionName: string; profileDetails: ProfileUI; profileInitialValues: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>, never>, any, any>> & Readonly<Pick<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>, never>> & Readonly<...>'.
  Property 'profileName' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>, never>, any, any>> & Readonly<Pick<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>, never>> & Readonly<...>'.
```

Comment: There isn't enough here to figure out what's going on. Also, impossible to type? In Typescript? Why not? My best *guess* is that you aren't calling your class component properly and Typescript is rejecting it.

Comment: Please tell me what extra info I can give.
The ProfileDetails.jsx component creates a method in componentDidMount and componentWillUnmount that I couldn't type:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    this.unblock = this.props.history.block((nextLocation, action) => {
      if (this.props.isFormDirty && !this.state.confirmedNavigation) {
        this.setState({
          nextLocation,
          nextAction: action,
          showPreventNavigationModal: true,
        });
      }
      return !this.props.isFormDirty;
    });
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    this.unblock();
  }
```

Comment: create a minimal repro example, preferably with a link to a TS playground that demonstrates the problem. Like, I'm trying to render class Foo (all the code for Foo) in functional component Bar (all the code for Bar) and the compiler gives this exact error.

Comment: What do you mean by "aren't calling you class component properly" ?

Comment: Like you've got a constructor parameter (i.e. React prop) that you think of as optional that isn't designated as such in a way the TS compiler understands, so it nixes the call because of a missing 'required' property in the props object.

Comment: Alright I get what you mean, it's just that I don't want the compiler to even check the parameters of that class component, being it a .jsx one and not a .tsx one. I updated the question with the exact error btw, until I find time to create a example.

Comment: That's not how it works. Even if you are importing a file from jsx, the TS compiler will infer the types of the things you're importing. And that's a good thing. In this case, it's telling you that you have an error in your code: you are passing a string where the code expects an element.

Comment: Please post your actual code somewhere.

Comment: I'll update as soon as I find some time which I'm seriously lacking right now

Comment: Added an answer. It was a combination of issues, thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This turned out to be a combination of 2 issues:

First, the error `Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'ElementType<HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement>>'` was referring to a totally different component, one that was using a `material-ui` `Typography` component, a question has been asked and answered here: [Typography component](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58277659/typography-component) . By the time I added this ticket I had upgraded my dependencies while trying a few things and the new version of `material-ui` was then throwing this new error.

Secondly, the error `Property 'profileName' does not exist on type 'IntrinsicAttributes & IntrinsicClassAttributes<Component<Pick<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>, never>, any, any>> & Readonly<Pick<RouteComponentProps<any, StaticContext, any>, never>> & Readonly<...>'.` 
which is showing up when rendering `.js` components within `.tsx` components, was indeed silenced using the syntax I have already included in my question:

```
  /* tslint:disable */
  const JSProfileDetails: any = ProfileDetails; 
  /* tslint:enable */

  return (
   <JSProfileDetails
        profileName={profileName}
        profileDetails={profileDetails}
        profileInitialValues={profileInitialValues}
      />
```

Thank for your time to everyone that gave their input.

Answer (score 0):

I just faced a very similar problem. It turned out I was calling the JSX child component with an invalid prop according to the proptypes on the subcomponent (or maybe TypeScript's inference?).

```js
const profile = someQuery.profile || {id: -1, name: "Guest"}
//...
<SubComponent profile={profile} />
```

`id` should be a string here, not number. Turning `-1` into `"-1"` solved my issue.